# Apache/PHP downloading index.php rather than displaying..?

Tags: php, apache, ssl

https://coinsafe.io/

I recently purchased and applied an SSL certificate.

After getting it all set-up, when I go to the site it downloads the index.php file...

There is code in the file but I cleared it out to see if it was my code causing it, and it downloaded it again and it was empty as expected.

The weird thing is when it downloads, it's not a .php file and it's called "download"

How can I fix this?

**Edit**

I am now getting this error `[Sat Nov 16 04:09:07 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`
 when I try to start Apache.

Comment: Are your sure that PHP is installed on your server? This usually is caused when it is not.

Comment: Is the compile mod_php extension enabled inside Apache? Does the config specify PHP processes .php files?

Comment: I did a CTRL+F in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf for "mod_php" and didn't come up with anyhting.

Comment: Depending on your config, it might be in another file. In CentOS, for instance, the packages put it in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`

Comment: It was working before I applied the SSL.

Comment: @SimonFischer there is a php5 in there and I wrote php5 and it returned `Module php5 already enabled`

Comment: Now it's not even loading at all....

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if Apache is trying to send a PHP file to your visitor, it means that Apache doesn't realise that the PHP is a script file.

This in turn means that apache hasn't loaded the php module, even if it's installed.

If you've done nothing else, there should be some sort of hint in your apache error.log, usually located in /var/log/apache2/ on ubuntu.

Also, in ubuntu php, you should have sym-links to php.conf and .load in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/

Comment: Thanks for trying.  Solved with this - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1361019